# How to position a repeating radial gradient within a card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, card, radial-gradients

I have a profile on a website that allows you to enter HTMl and CSS in your settings to customize your page. My goal is to have the center of a repeating radial gradient start behind a circular picture within a .card so the rings form around it.

My problem is that when I add any sort of positioning (like "at top") the gradient completely disappears.

I've tried putting the CSS directly within the HTML instead to see if it was the card's id messing with it, but I'm getting the same result.

When I put the same code into jsfiddle and add the positioning, it works for some reason.

`background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle,#000, #000 20px, #fff 20px, #fff 40px)`

Result:

[image]

`background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle at top,#000, #000 20px, #fff 20px, #fff 40px)`

Result:

[image]

[My profile](https://toyhou.se/jelliedbro)

```css
#card1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: inherit;
}

#card1 .card {
  border: none;
  background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, #000, #000 20px, #fff 20px, #fff 40px)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-block card border-0 px-0 py-5" style="margin-top: -58px; background-color: transparent">
  <div class="container text-center px-0" style="letter-spacing: .25px; font-size: 10pt;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-md-0 mb-3" id="card1">
        <!--------- SIDE STATS -------------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="card d-block modal-open h-100">
          <div class="card-header" style="background-color:black">
            <!-------------- CHARACTER NAME ----------------------------------------->
            <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase mb-0" style="font-weight:300; letter-spacing:1px;">
              Name</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <!---------------- FOCAL IMAGE -- WILL SCALE ACROSS SCREEN SIZES ---------->
            <img class="image mb-3" src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/thumbnails/47592316_Upv.png" style=";background-size:contain;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:150px;border-radius:100%;aspect-ratio:1;">
            </img><br>

            <p style="margin:0px 0px 10px;word-wrap:break-word;">
              <p style="font-family:Grandstander">
                testteste tdis udfufjifjieof jiosjf ijsdpojoisdp jsopd jodisdjos gjiofdsjgosdfgjio djfewiaof fewjfiwoefqwieofjoi fejiwfjweifje fewjfiewjfowe
              </p>

              <hr class="my-2 faded">

              <div class="justify-content-between">
                <span class="text-uppercase text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px;">
                  Gender</span>
                <span>Content</span>
              </div>
              <hr class="my-2 faded">

              <div class="justify-content-between">
                <span class="text-uppercase text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px;">
                  Age</span>
                <span>Content</span>
              </div>
              <hr class="my-2 faded">

              <div class="justify-content-between">
                <span class="text-uppercase text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px;">
                  Role</span>
                <span>(what they do)</span>
              </div>
              <hr class="my-2 faded">

              <div class="justify-content-between">
                <span class="text-uppercase text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px;">HTML</span>
                <!-- CODING CREDIT -- LEAVE THIS -------------->
                <span>@Pinky</span>
              </div>
              <hr class="my-2 faded">

              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto text-uppercase text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px;">Theme
                </div>
                <div class="col px-2"></div>
                <div class="col-auto text-primary">
                  Song Name <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>

                  <!--- INSTRUCTIONS: fill in the "ID_HERE" with a youtube video id, --------->
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID_HERE?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity: .001" class="h-100 w-100" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Pastebin isn't a valid way to share code on SO, and your link wasn't working anyway. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then update the demo above to show the problem.

Comment: Protip: You _really_ want to stop putting all those inline styles in your markup. It makes working and interpreting your document much more difficult, and you have a huge amount of repetition. Use custom classes and CSS.